# as of 4/2015 OS X Kindle App: Where are the books located?

Tags: macos, kindle

After I updated my Kindle for Mac app 2 mos. ago I can no longer find the azw book files on my Mac to convert them so I can read them on my KOBO ereader. I use to find them in a My Kindle Content file but that has disappeared. I have Ult. DRM & Calibre but they won't work without the azw files, and I can't find them on my mac anymore. Can anyone help me?
The answers on this site about this are years old & do not apply to my problem.

Comment: With the latest Kindle version, it's here: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Kindle/My\ Kindle\ Content`

Answer (score 14):

Kindle.app now uses the Apple Sandbox functionality.

This means that it can only affect and see files in a subdirectory under ~/Library/Containers. The .azw files are in `~/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data/Library/Application Support/Kindle/My Kindle Content`

This directory is shown in the Kindle app in Preferences->General as the value of Content Folder and it appears that this can be changed there.

Comment: +1 for the **Preferences -> General** info, which seems to apply to all versions.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to [OS X Kindle App: Where are the books located?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16486/os-x-kindle-app-where-are-the-books-located) indicates that Kindle books get stored in `~/Documents/My\ Kindle\ Content`. If this folder doesn't exist or is empty, you can open Terminal and run

```
find ~ -name '*.azw' -print
```

to search for them within your user folder.

Comment: As noted in the question the latest Kindle release on 20.4.15 has changed that

Comment: That `find` command works well to find the files quickly, regardless. +1

Comment: Mine are still located in the location specified in this answer. +1 for the search command.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the Kindle Content folder, the actual folders you need to navigate through will be visible. In Finder, click on either the Boot Drive on your desktop, usually your only drive, or on the Boot drive, or the item in your left hand panel that corresponds to your User name, and then navigate to the correct path is as follows:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data/Library/Application Support/Kindle/My Kindle Content/
```

Once you have access to your Kindle content, you can then copy the files to another folder to be processed for conversion, or whatever you plan to do with them. Once you've found your content folder, you can then go into Preferences in the Kindle App and change your destination folder.